# Return Values from one table that have no entries in another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this example, I'm trying to return a list of values (in this case, company names) that have no entries in another table (entries in this case meaning invoices). In other words, I'm trying to return a list of companies that have no invoices. Here is my code:

`Select CompanyName
From tblCompany join tblInvoice
    ON tblCompany.CompanyID = tblInvoice.CompanyID 
Where tblCompany.CompanyID NOT IN
    (Select CompanyID
    From tblInvoice)`

What I'm trying to get is this:

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCpKP.jpg)

However, when I run the code, no values show up. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Remove the join statement.

Comment: OMG, I feel like such an idiot. That's my achilles heel of programming, the minor things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join and filter on nulls:

```
select CompanyName
from tblCompany
left join tblInvoice on tblCompany.CompanyID = tblInvoice.CompanyID 
where tblInvoice.CompanyID is null
```

This works because missed joins return nulls in the joined table's values.

Comment: You don't need `distinct` here. There is no duplicates provided `CompanyName` is unique in `tblCompany`.

Comment: @Alex I can't believe I forgot that missed joins get exactly one row. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select  CompanyName
From    tblCompany 
Where   tblCompany.CompanyID NOT IN    
    (   Select  CompanyID
        From    tblInvoice)
```

That is get all the `CompanyName` from `tblCompany` where the `CompanyID` not exists in the `tblInvoice`.

Or you can try the below one,

```
select CompanyName
from   tblCompany
left join tblInvoice on tblCompany.CompanyID = tblInvoice.CompanyID 
where  tblInvoice.CompanyID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query for desired results.

```
Select CompanyName
From tblCompany 
left join tblInvoice
ON tblCompany.CompanyID = tblInvoice.CompanyID 
Where tblInvoice.CompanyID IS NULL
```